# In the navigation bar, the navigation options are not in the same line

Tags: css, nav

I am trying to get the navigation links on the same line, but i am unable to. I did all I could, and appreciate any help.Thank you guys. just give me some hints or direction. I can provide the html part if needed.

```
/* ============================================================
  RESET - http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
============================================================ */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/* ============================================================
  BOX SIZING & CLEARFIX
============================================================ */
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* ============================================================
  HTML & BODY
============================================================ */
body {
  background-color: #b4b4b4;
  color: #787878;
  font-family: Ubuntu;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

/* ============================================================
  PRIMARY STRUCTURE
============================================================ */
.masthead {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

main {
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

/* ============================================================
  INFO BAR
============================================================ */
.info-bar {
  padding: 3px 0;
  background-color: #026ab3;
  text-align: right;
}

.logo h1 a {
  color: white; 
  float: left;
  font-family: Josefin Slab;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-decoration: none; 
}

.content ul a {
  color: red;
  right: 0;
  padding:0;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}





/* ============================================================
  HEADER & SITE TITLE
============================================================ */
/* header */
header .branding {
  padding: 20px 0;
}
header .logo {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
header .logo img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
header .social {
  text-align: center;
}
header .social a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 5px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-image: url("../img/core/social-light.png");
  background-image: url("../img/core/social-light.svg"), none;
  background-size: 180px 30px;
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  header .branding {
    padding-left: 60px;
  }
  header .logo {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -60px;
    float: left;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
  }
  header .logo img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
  }
  header .social {
    padding: 15px 0;
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
  }
}
/* site title */
.site-title {
  padding: 5px 0;
  background-color: #818181;
  text-align: center;
}
.site-title {
  color: #fff;
}

/* ============================================================
  FOOTER
============================================================ */
footer {
  padding: 20px 0;
}
footer .asides {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
footer aside {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
footer nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
footer nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
footer nav a {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  color: #fff;
}
footer .logo {
  text-align: center;
}
footer .logo img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
footer .copyright {
  text-align: center;
}
footer .copyright small {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
}
footer .copyright a {
  color: #818181;
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  footer aside {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 33.3333%;
  }
  footer nav ul {
    text-align: left;
  }
  footer nav li {
    display: block;
  }
  footer nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
  }
  footer .logo {
    text-align: right;
  }
}
/* ============================================================
  FUSION ADS
============================================================ */
#fusionads {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 20;
  padding: 20px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: -2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

#fusionads .fusion-wrap {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  width: 130px;
}

#fusionads a.fusion-text {
  display: block;
  color: #787878;
}

#fusionads a.fusion-img {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#fusionads a.fusion-img img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

#fusionads a.fusion-poweredby {
  color: #b4b4b4;
}
#fusionads a.fusion-poweredby:hover {
  color: #818181;
}

#close-fusionad {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 30;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #282828;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

/* ============================================================
  TEXT LEVEL SEMANTICS
============================================================ */
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #b4b4b4;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover {
  color: #818181;
}
```

Comment: html link :   http://pastebin.com/BZganjYQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your alignment.and remove that auto margin. It works.

Answer (score 0):

The reason to remove auto margin , is it automatically assigns the alignment and the navigation cannot be seen in the same line.

Comment: No need for two answers..Just edit your orginal with the added information